# print_r not understanding a portion of the output

Tags: php, serialization

I run a print_r command on $_POST and I am getting the following response:

```
s:1289:"Array
(
    [id_master] => 12
    [id_controller] => 4
    [JSON] => {"uuid":"i~b1dad2c95c3efdc8521c84cd2891084289b9754b","relsno":102}
)";
```

Any idea what the s:1289: is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a PHP serialized object. Here, `s:1289` refers to the datatype, `s` for a string, and its length, which is 1289 characters.